# Need a path from Android ContentResolver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

Following the deprecation of `requestLegacyExternalStorage` in the `Manifest.xml` file, I'm trying to use the Android guideline on data storage:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

In my app I'm using a command line tool (FFMpeg) to generate a video. I need to define a path in my command but really can't figure out how to get a full path from the `Uri` I get from the `ContentResolver` class.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible?

No. And, even if it were, likely it would be useless. You do not have direct filesystem access for write operations to arbitrary paths. You need to have `ffmpeg` write to some place that you *do* have direct filesystem access for writes (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`).